# mvc3 noobie: my style sheet does not link properly in IE (but works in chrome)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm learning ASP.net MVC 3 with the music store tutorial--but translating the C# into VB. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3

I have downloaded the stylesheet for the tutorial and replaced content/site.css with the style sheet for the music store site. If I open the file Site.css located in the content folder, then the code I see in my site.css looks exactly like the sample code from mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com.

If I run the app and open it in IE, the style sheet does not 'link up.' But if I run it in chrome, it does.

What's going on?

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the page with ctrl-F5?

Comment: I guess browser cached your old css. clear browser cache and see

Comment: @MystereMan that was it. what was that about?

Comment: ctrl-F5 refreshes the page without cache.  ctrl-f5 is your friend.  Always use ctrl-f5 when you have css issues.

Comment: @MystereMan so browsers cache the CSS for pages sometimes? and ie was using the outdated cached css?

Comment: Yes, browsers usually cache css, not just sometimes.. almost always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear your cache, either via internet options, or by using ctrl-f5.

Another option is to place a random querystring parameter on your css link in your html:

```
<link href=".......css?id=1" /> // 2, 3, etc..
```